# Error -- Cast to Number failed for value "NaN" (type number) at path "totalOrders"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, api, express

I created an API for my project but in an endpoint, there occurred an error that I couldn't fix.

```
const fullOrdersForService = service.totalOrders
const updatedFullOrdersForService = fullOrdersForService + 1
const updateService = await Service.findOneAndUpdate({_id:serviceId}, { totalOrders: updatedFullOrdersForService },{new:true})
```

Absolutely in the above code, I checked the type of `service.totalOrders` and its output as the number and also `service.totalOrders` came from a schema so there isn't any possibility to change the type of that into string or NaN. I checked whether it is NaN and it is also false and it is not a NaN. I still wonder how that error occurred.
But an error occured like following.

> ```
> messageFormat: undefined,
> stringValue: '"NaN"',
> kind: 'Number',
> value: NaN,
> path: 'totalOrders',
> reason: AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: The expression evaluated to a falsy value:
> assert.ok(!isNaN(val))
> ```

My schema of the `Service.totalOrders` can be seen in the below.

```
totalOrders:{
  type:Number,
  required:true,
  default:0
}
```

My schema of the `Seller.totalOrders` can be seen in the below.

```
totalOrders:{
  type:Number,
  required:true,
  default:0
}
```

```
const fullOrdersForService = service.totalOrders  
const updatedFullOrdersForService = fullOrdersForService + 1 
const updateService = await Service.findOneAndUpdate({_id:serviceId}, { totalOrders: updatedFullOrdersForService },{new:true})
```

I just tried this code and the error which I mentioned above occurred.

Answer (score 0):

first `console.log(fullOrdersForService )` and `console.log(updatedFullOrdersForService )` to check wather it's number or not then

if  updatedFullOrdersForService is correct but string use `parseInt(updatedFullOrdersForService )` before updating